# xamarin.forms: View isnt fullscren on iOS borders (slight corner at the edges)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to make the top carouselview fullscreen. However, there is a slight border to the left and to the upper part of the every picture in the carouselview. If I set a background color to the grid, it gets rendered into the corners, but not with the picture. This code works on Android, the problem exists only on iOS. Any Ideas?

```
   <Grid>

        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                <RowDefinition Height="285"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <Grid Grid.Row="0" >

                
                <CarouselView VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Start"  Loop="false" x:Name="carouselview" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
                


            </Grid>
```

The template selector:

```
<Grid    RowSpacing="0"                     HeightRequest="280">
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

                    <Image 
                             Source="{Binding fullPic}" 
                             Aspect="Fill"
                                x:Name="img_pic"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

                    <Grid Margin="0,0,4,4"
                                HorizontalOptions="End"
                                VerticalOptions="End">

                        <BoxView 
                                CornerRadius="20"
                                IsVisible="{Binding isNumberVisible}"
                                BackgroundColor="#99000000"/>

                        <Label 
                                 Text="{Binding number}" 
                                 FontSize="15"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 FontFamily="Font_11"
                                 TextColor="White"
                                                            />
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
```

[image: See the issue here]

Comment: How about setting `Margin="-2"` for your Carousel. Also, try to open another app, like photos, to see if the blank line is still there.

Comment: The Margin option doesnt work. This issue only exists on this code here

Comment: Could you provide more code for me to reproduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the main grid of the datatemplate of the carouselview fixed the issue:

Margin="-2"